# Linux: Gnu-Tar Excludes

Tags: linux, tar

I'm trying to perform a full backup of a Linux server using GNU-Tar. The file system looks like this:

```
├── backup
├── data
│   ├── d1
│   ├── d2
│   └── tmp
│       ├── tt1
│       ├── tt2
│       └── tt3
├── exclude
├── home
│   ├── a
│   ├── b
│   ├── c
│   └── d
├── proc
│   ├── pa
│   ├── pb
│   ├── pc
│   └── pd
├── sys
│   ├── s1
│   ├── s2
│   ├── s3
│   └── s4
└── tmp
    ├── t1
        ├── t2
        └── t3
```

I'd like to exclude tmp and proc, but preserve /data/tmp/*.
However, using the following command:

```
$tar -X exclude -cvpf -  * | wc -l
```

with this exclude file:

```
$cat exclude 
        proc/*
        tmp/*
```

I find that /data/tmp is excluded as well.
How can I include data/tmp whilst excluding tmp?
More importantly, how should I understand tar's wildcard interpretation and exclude pattern matching. Does every pattern in the exclude file behave like a grep?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying the `tar` command to `tar -X exclude -cvpf - .` (ie, change the `*` to a `.`) and modifying the exclude file to say

```
./proc/*
./tmp/*
```

**Edit**: really?  Works for me.  Here's my directory structure:

```
|-- a
| |-- foo
|-- b
| |-- bar
| |-- tmp
| | |-- farr
|-- tmp
| |-- frotz
```

Here's the contents of my `../exclude` file

```
./tmp/*
```

Then I do `tar cvf ../test.tar -X ../exclude .` and get

```
./
./b/
./b/bar
./b/tmp/
./b/tmp/farr
./tmp/
./a/
./a/foo
```

Note that the contents of `./b/tmp` are included (`./b/tmp/farr` is picked up) but those of `./tmp` are not (`./tmp/frotz` is not picked up).

tar is `tar (GNU tar) 1.26` on Fedora 16.

Comment: ...doesn't work: data/tmp is still excluded

Comment: interesting effects using the suggested solution: with BSD Tar (on mac), proc, tmp, and data/tmp are excluded. With Gnu-Tar, none of them are excluded.

Comment: My CentOS 6.3 (GNU tar) 1.23 works as expected too.

Comment: Ok, thanks, works as expected with Debian and CentOS GNU Tar. Apparently my Mac GNU Tar is messed up.

Comment: @alpha-lemming Your question only mentions GNU tar on Linux. If a Mac is somehow relevant here, it should be in your question.